# Velocity/position and derivatives

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I don't have the answer, so I'm wondering if I am correct.

$V_a$ is the approximate velocity.
$$V_a(t) = \dfrac{\text{Position}(t+0.1)-\text{Position}(t)}{0.1}.$$

The position is $P(t)=0.5+0.5\sin(t)$

Predict what approximate speed you will measure at time $t$. Here are my steps:

1. $V_a(t) = \dfrac{0.5+0.5\sin(t+0.1)-(0.5+0.5\sin(t))}{0.1}$
2. $V_a(t) =\dfrac{0.5+0.5\sin(t)+\sin(0.1)-0.5-0.5\sin(t)}{0.1}$
3. $V_a(t) = \dfrac{\sin(0.1)}{0.1}$

Also, the derivative of the position is $P'(t)=0.5\cos(t)$, right?

Comment: you made a mistake in point 2. as $sin(A+B)=sinAosB + cosAsinB$

Comment: Your comment at the end is correct. $P'(t)=0.5\cos(t)$

Answer (score 1):

In the $2$nd step:

$$\sin(t+0.1)=\sin(t)\cos(0.1)+\cos(t)\sin(0.1)$$

It should proceed like

$V_a(t) = \dfrac{Position(t+0.1)-Position(t)}{0.1}$

$V_a(t) = \dfrac{0.5+0.5\sin(t+0.1)-(0.5+0.5\sin(t))}{0.1}$

$V_a(t) = \dfrac{0.5(\sin(t)\cos(0.1)+\cos(t)\sin(0.1))-0.5\sin(t)}{0.1}$

$V_a(t) = \dfrac{0.5(\sin(t)(\cos(0.1)-1)+\cos(t)\sin(0.1))}{0.1}$

Approximate $\cos(0.1)\approx1$ and $\sin(0.1)\approx0.1$.

$V_a(t) = 0.5\cos(t)$

Answer (score 1):

In step $2$: you cannot "distribute" the $\sin$ function over a sum of angles (which are its argument). $$\;\sin(A + B) \neq \sin(A) + \sin(B)$$

You **can**, however, use the identity:

$$\sin(A+B)=\sin A \cos B + \cos A \sin B$$ and substitute $t$ for $A$ and $0.1$ for $B$:

$$\sin(t+0.1)=\sin(t) \cos(0.1) + \cos(t) \sin(0.1)$$

The derivative you've included **is indeed** correct: $P'(t)=0.5\cos(t)$

Comment: This is what I got:      $V_a(t)=\dfrac{0.5+0.5[sin(t)cos(0.1)+cos(t)sin(0.1)]-0.5-0.5sin(t)}{0.1}$
$V_a(t)= 5sin(t)cos(0.1)+5cos(t)sin(0.1)-5sin(t)$

Comment: Yes, indeed! That's correct! You now have an expression for approximate velocity at time $t$.

Comment: Thank you! Really appreciate it.